# Flutter local notification not working here is my error:

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, push

Hello i just added flutter local notifications package to my project, I watch a video tutorial step by step but when I press the button nothing appear, no push notification here is my error message:

StackTrace:

```
E/flutter (13614): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (13614): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:177:18)
E/flutter (13614): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13614): #2      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart:215:7)
E/flutter (13614): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13614): #3      LocalNotificationService.showNotification (package:electromobility_flutter_application/services/local_notification_service.dart:56:5)
E/flutter (13614): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13614): #4      _WalletState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:electromobility_flutter_application/Account/Wallet/WalletPage.dart:309:31)
E/flutter (13614): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13614):
```

Comment: Share your full code to show a notification and your full error

Answer (score 0):

- Stop the app
- Run flutter clean
- Run flutter pub get

This should fix your issue

Comment: no its not working